# subtração no Diff R software

Tags: r, diff

meu nivel no R é iniciante caso vocês possam me ajudar com um problema ficarei grato.

eu tenho uma função matemática que me gera um vetor, e tenho que fazer uma subtração entre o valor da segunda coluna menos o valor da primeira coluna, entre o valor da terceira coluna e o valor da segunda ... etc. Porém como não tem um valor entre a primeira coluna e a anterior o valor deve ser zero, utilizei a função diff para realizar isso, mas não obtive sucesso. Teria como vocês me ajudarem? Exemplos:

Exemplo abaixo.

0,5863 0

0,5908 0,0045 ; 0, 5908-0,5863 = 0,0045

0,5954 0,0046 ; 0,5954 – 0,5908 = 0,0046

codigo do R

```
BWGmax <- 32
K <- 0.0118
Xm <- 26
SD <- 1.00850750718386
mean.b<- 30
DLmeth <- 0.0273
CDiet <- 0.329
CDLMET <- 1
WB <- 1
number <- 4300
BWG.EN <- 1.3
AMEn <- 2.975
Temp <-31

mt <- (300.14 - 14.61 * Temp + 0.2876 * Temp**2)
MCic <- seq(from = 210, to = 290, by = 1.9)
MCisimulate <- rep(MCic, number)
BW <- 0.0223*WG^0.8944
WG <- c()

for(i in 1:number) { 
  WG[i] <- ((sqrt(-2*log(runif(1, 0, 1)))*sin(2*pi*runif(1, 0, 1)))*SD)+(mean.b)
}

t <- matrix(BW, nrow = 43, ncol = 100)

BW2 <- apply(t, 1, mean)

BWG2 <- if ((BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-(Xm-BW))))) > WG) { WG } else { (BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-(Xm-BW))))) } mean(BWG2)

k <- matrix(BWG2, nrow = 43, ncol = 100)

BWG3 <- apply(k, 1, mean)

FI <- (mt*(BW^0.75)+(BWG2*BWG.EN))/AMEn

h <- matrix(FI, nrow = 43, ncol = 100)

FI2 <- apply(h, 1, mean)

MCiper <- ((MCic/1000)/FI2)*100

MCincrease <- diff(MCiper)
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: adicione o código a pergunta amigo.

Comment: Clique em [edit] para informar o código

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer. Seus objeto final, `MCincrease` é um vetor, logo, não tem colunas. Você quer subtrair cada valor do anterior? Se for, deve usar `diff` mesmo, o primeiro valor será ignorado se você quiser pode incluir um 0 para não perdê-lo: `diff(c(0, MCiper))`.

Comment: Além disso, o código contem o erro do `if` que você resolveu na outra pergunta, seria ideal corrigi-lo.